# Regex from loops

Tags: javascript

```
this.personRegex = (input) => {
            return new RegExp(persons.map((person) => {
                return person.fullname;
            }).join("|"), "gi");
        }
```

the above give me :

```
/lwe|alvin/gi;
```

How do I get the below:

```
/\b(?:lwe|alvin)\b/gi;
```

Comment: As the additional stuff does not seem to be related to the number of persons, simply do it in the code **Regex("\b(?:"+ map() + ")\b")**.

Comment: By adding `\b` to the beginning and end of the regexp you are creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
personRegex = (persons) => {
    return new RegExp("\\b(?:"+persons.map((person, i) => {
        return person.fullname;
    }).join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");
}

console.log(personRegex([{
    fullname: "lwe"
}, {
    fullname: "alvin"
}]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do string concatenation:

```
var personAlternatives = persons.map((person) => { return person.fullname; }).join("|")
this.personRegex = (input) => {
    return new RegExp('\\b(?:' + personAlternatives + ')\\b', "gi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the least overhead:

```js
function buildRegex(array){
  var reg;
  var mapResult = array.map((item) => {
    return item.attr;
  }).join("|");
  return new RegExp("\\b(?:"+mapResult+")\\b", "gi");
}

console.log(buildRegex([{attr:"a"},{attr:"b"}]));
```

Comment: What kind of overhead, compared to what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template strings, with `String.raw` to avoid worrying about double backslashes:

```js
personRegex = input => 
  new RegExp(
    String.raw`\b(?:${input.map(person => person.fullname).join("|")})\b`,
    "gi");

console.log(personRegex([{fullname: 'Bob'}, {fullname: 'Sally'}]));
```

In the real world, you would want to escape any possible special regexp characters in the input. For more information on doing that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).